# Votes to Close a Question

Tags: support, voting, vote-to-close, votes

I am able to vote to close my own questions where appropriate and I have 24 votes remaining at the moment.

[image: Vote to Close]

24 seems like an odd number (though quite generous) to start with but I guess its just 25 take away the one that I was about to place.

I was just wondering if I were to use them all, how often do they get restocked?

Comment: @they get 'restocked' every 24 hours when the UTC date changes.

Comment: Thats very generous, I guess its only there to stop users spaming close votes

Comment: Here's an artifact for you.    http://meta.mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/1443/when-is-a-day-in-se-over

Answer (score 3):

Close votes are replenished every 24 hours when the UTC/GMT date changes.

Comment: award yourself the answer.  You will get a badge

Comment: In 2 days, thanks I didn't know if it was okay to rewrite a comment as an answer. Sometimes people give the best answers in the comments and all I want to do is accept it as an answer!